# QGIS fails to render ArcGIS Feature Service layers after PC Sleep

Tags: qgis-3, feature-service

***UPDATE***
I have done some more investigation into this error, so there are some updates below. The issues seems to be isolated to *rendering only.*

I have a QGIS project which has some layers from an ArcGIS Feature Service. These work when first added.
If I leave the project open overnight, and the PC goes into sleep mode, upon waking up the machine, logging in - QGIS is obviously still open and running, however - the ArcGIS Feature Service layers fail to render in the morning.

Note that I have just tested retrieving the attribute layer - this has worked! (40k records have returned). So it appears that the failure is only on the rendering.

If I simply remove the layer, then re-add the layer from the ervice connection, the same layer now renders correctly.

The developer logs inside of QGIS for a failed map render are:

```
  {
"Bytes Received": 64,
"Bytes Total": 64,
"Cache (control)": "Load from cache if available, otherwise load from network",
"Cache (save)": "Can store result in cache",
"Headers": {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 QGIS/31603"
},
"ID": "\\providers\\arcgisrest\\qgsarcgisrestutils.cpp:512 (QgsArcGisRestUtils::queryService)",
"Initiator": "QgsArcGisRestUtils",
"Operation": "GET",
"Query": {
  "f": "json",
  "geometry": "566496.853214,7433289.796526,566776.965816,7433503.860811",
  "geometryType": "esriGeometryEnvelope",
  "returnIdsOnly": "true",
  "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelEnvelopeIntersects",
  "where": "1=1"
},
"Replies": 2,
"Reply": {
  "Cache (result)": "Read from network",
  "Headers": {
    "Cache-Control": "public, must-revalidate, max-age=0",
    "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Date": "Tue, 31 Aug 2021 02:35:15 GMT",
    "ETag": "bf78c824",
    "Persistent-Auth": "true",
    "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0, ",
    "Set-Cookie": "AGSWA_ROLES=Dtizm2hEKputr+rbuWQIpdNuGfVSIs051rtNqFjfhZx5gRgytClqzPjpLocKVZbAw5e8EMxJCVrpplKUjxeG9Xcc0shZFnCkHBJ0b0AcH0vPg1JKwOFo0hbirmafxHCxzDrpftncRdr2XJ6+0DxmGliSwaec77B/12/8+C90CzdIyllE0Cmlx94kREX4Qhh1luBU+HfZo8qBCY6rU4Wt/zXPLvxLC0oRN7dtwuVoFNeRDrC4jgTbaSP8tT++aoucFm96ENnhQU2Db+BY+HBbTys2mtlm4uigOrU722rMskK3tm/t/eJbhipy4V4xdx6JM3gb2sdxoMCRmp1KRiZVSfsxN9B8u0QYjw/Vl2p7TAz1vPOfl4fx5qs24r6/v1xxQPzGcQdqnKr4fRQt26LgbDneugZ1PfXJChfeOFilpJ21ZWuDzNYpyyYlTXEyRei2dQLH+6cCI+sZz+m50glxSts5WTL/eiwyCxwlUC2Ihvge11aJNKFem/P0xpHyDjrA3FlqOmri7VH86XHK4JFKISCelf5KoNHd5fdBjduOfOEV8sc+3N+TIL10hLa0TA8LVY/r4fJkFhap8aE3NVPYO8JpdkWQmCX7dglAc8zajZQohbh8+XRUIdqGuGnSD43gBUgJB4624BJccY7Qvzuyz/9qw5xjOOhx3OJ+O67UzeiQC3uWwXe8Sxr3B+a+U+KoNMH5C+ujPw4LnM+2FEert5UVjvCbYGN0OERk9TGh4Wdwc4uswv17hF4NP1oQqZNVfG8KIU+3JTib/FrOTh/tvC6qSSpfHxK+ivGRbYOUlMiacSBKhjPoOM+BZ+165hy7PZJK+RvS7+23nqbIBtwh2x1+2Ah6TRb0GOp8XAjFnnDWUkZ2nTyey8SDmBzHMaj0QD+nIVKC9JB5CQ14kPGtRHGl7RfbLNcOiZ1Sec5hruWPV4xXEeXbTY7BNNtCTvVUj6ou1McVB40esZ7gmBW8ftBM+QTk6Js9uk1CE0Lx9cscydvXZlIHdihoQ84oDQru6lleY+gHPaEnfslCAaK/4a4IPGuFB25HujfGwGPy3sNaWxml0A863eRxOALB2GkjvJvet4f8abeuP3SoSSxk8ylF084RvsmbKXcOAHr8uPcY1kezftGVk+6YaT7cjxu7qTXsC+OMds/6dJFcSsGmj97bz3qC0PW0YYl8Y3uX+tlYenXR2MpxNZS/0TXZSvEoCzdtU/lTLqprcRKUO49wX19T6P6dFeR8XLfi2KWrx+P+pEoOcxpz225yFrDe138++s76mw1I9RU7D1TWG6MIu6RvF1sgAZ9TAa8DfgI78V96IM0BSNMiffAObw6DkzYEEAh8pX/wOEO+TSmQidK8ca4syUSDlBPvxGFEV5LU2+xEbf+13TnwH0sAnIZh5J3n8exi7pn3HnRNiongcBbwzv7vSEe17n3lMzT09Wido0shdbKr9x6NH5/EuscIb0lPgB/wQYqsUKyFkYo8qoT8uAcLF1LMLo23u7Z7mZ74wvl7rYeyeSjQbVqli4axCP6djvm4c205IGx6aiie+dV/tveELpAhwtqzS9I/2IofOvCZ7Hv6UOMvp8YxjAfEhJArcpEucariOUBTZupx/9v4at5S3PeQkSKOIYZGhQGgCbtdDJdptAhwsGbelODvZ90QNZH6T17rCnUmdHSffXfiXQQnZVnSyaWJKlCiv3GLUfkjqiEBtKdAS7KHlE39iDwiVfAl+EUkdry54YU/NOspvucj3cbbKvC/D0kti9pXPKkksyMe9VzVPktLa45n8IUQ0F+JmJbZCVG2daSKChkQMbW5zHcLLJ24VxS5moGEH1CcbhqlUs9zKQ4waDzPvvH9p5AtdMFr6rXXXOd8O2bPyCLPrwjkE624kBMxSYds0dcgMclxra8eOikOEF2VsyPGo/5LQNaj33KbnaUW/1XbDKozcNPVkfmn1MR7oTEd4rccZ2hQ6m+yyd/8pOFkg1LG72GZFkg0EleGGeZ26CORd420rdz6qm28XLOE3ZsRcayilf0T1GMTUUWwPhnpfL31ixztuRzCWvztVWQ8gauR7jr1g5Q+OwKNSqgyk4RU7XzrJcRBLxnk+grEQLicZZdkd/3Iha+FvBUl5Au3IKGSPQx2eor84IBceBPPeY5+kCyr0ap6gARPFyxAmb/NEkgb3BE48T+Qmz+hUNf5x/dENt2osif3Fiilxf4aE+ZxCfcWq3p8we1QF9NNZObg+OmZe7gWS0Mpawgcz+aAX6Weg6HAA1RCnqLLcSKa3xFCuJMXKMquGJJmPwwQGQQGMBb3f1KVhsh6RHFwkK0sInEfi05dTWiPF3Yd2XI6OoyXf4ZxnGYL+cSpF9L/VrUD7379CvsPG101oL6LSZmfL7uXyFUvJzBZUDhewAXOjfqAigbSQe8veOZypG+SrCJJICGWEGOlmAlNwCgVpXqX4KrPW7B3j+e9CgTb0fvqfV24sd1TPydZez86BNpCINHXIA25hGmkzE/PRjm8wzQjvEgBgSO44dHaT7LwgwKZ+aaM+HS2PnS18iHQUpPo759T5dVIBti1htExKa6URtC1cf4x9zZ+rQroT8mEvTKqmnpoIoSWeRmZZsOnBoJcKHy300lmoHJuTr89Ht66jogK8chRK9n+6Dl2JRt/jx/FG8UHBAK8VPyapNbbkpGqEVK42UNMU7IQ1QLOWpZueaijXfWG3tTpnkNPsavtMxDFdz7ndwq3hzhE1i+6Vyjj5gtA7ZDi0bIt20IK71uHOqgBao1/lw==; expires=Tue, 31-Aug-2021 02:40:15 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly",
    "Vary": "Origin",
    "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
    "x-esri-ftiles-cache-compress": "true"
  },
  "Status": "200"
},
"Thread": "0x0000024d1e1961b0",
"Total time (ms)": 237,
"URL": "https://XYZ.erver.org/arcgis/rest/services/Approvals/Approvals_layer/FeatureServer/1/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnIdsOnly=true&geometry=566496.853214,7433289.796526,566776.965816,7433503.860811&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelEnvelopeIntersects"
```

(Please note i have edited the URL to hide the internal details of the server. )

My original theory was that the token that QGIS has requested and received upon initial layer connection, expired overnight. When performing a map request, it is trying to do so with an expired token.
But the above Set-Cookie information is suggestive of requesting a new token each time. I may be wrong here, so im now not sure.
the fact that attributes are returned but not map render now confuses my theory. Unless token requests only occur upon map request.

My question is two-fold, so ill keep this post focused on confirming the issue.

So this question is - Does anyone know why this issue is occurring? Or is there some further debugging I could perform?

FYI am using QGIS 3.16 on Windows and the ArcGIS Feature Service is configured with 'No Authentication'. (its all single sign on here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently upgraded QGIS to 3.18.

Since then, it appears that the above issue no longer is occurring.

My suggestion is that if anyone is still getting this issue with 3.18 please post here, but otherwise my recommendation is that 3.18 resolves this issue.